# C# Panel autoscroll doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel with a picturebox on it. When the content of the picturebox is too large I want scrollbars. I've set the autoscroll set to true on the panel. But when the content of the picturebox is larger then the height of the panel/picturebox no scrollbars are shown.

My panel is anchored top, left, bottom, right. The picturebox is also anchored top, left, bottom, right.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll have to set the `SizeMode` property to `AutoSize` which causes the PictureBox to automatically resize to the picture's size.

And I think you should drop the anchors and only anchor to the top left. The rest is taken care of automatically by the panel. Because otherwise the PictureBox would probably honor the anchors, being unable to resize itself larger than the panel it contains – leading to no scrollbars again.

Comment: "I think you should drop the anchors and only anchor to the top left" save my day, ty!

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx):

> There is currently a limitation in Windows Forms that prevents all classes derived from `ScrollableControl` from acting properly when both `RightToLeft` is enabled and `AutoScroll` is set to `True`. For example, let's say that you place a control such as `Panel`— or a container class derived from `Panel` (such as `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`) — on your form. If you set `AutoScroll` on the container to `True` and then set the `Anchor` property on one or more of the controls inside of the container to `Right`, then no scrollbar ever appears. The class derived from `ScrollableControl` acts as if `AutoScroll` were set to `False`.

Comment: Is any mention made of `RightToLeft`?

Comment: I meant in the question! I'm not seeing it. This answer only pertains when both `RightToLeft` and `AutoScroll` are enabled .. but I don't think the question describes such a scenario?

Comment: The limitation is observed when the flags are enabled. OP may or may not have that flags, it should check if that is the cause.

Comment: Fair call, fair call. :)

Answer (score 7):

The picturebox should not be anchored bottom and right. Instead, resize it to the content to display.

Answer (score 4):

For me below code helped in adding scrollbar:

```
Panel2.Controls.Clear();
Panel2.AutoScroll = false;
Panel2.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
Panel2.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;

Panel2.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: It feels very hacky, but it actually did the trick in a very special situation. Darn side-effects :-)

Comment: I don't know why, but I also need this piece of code to gets scroll bar...

Answer (score 0):

Change the Panel's Border Style to Fixed Single and then the Panel's Auto Scroll Property to True.