# Why does the menu strip white out when subscribing to a picture box paint event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint, picturebox

I have a form with a `MenuStrip` and a `PictureBox`. I subscribe to the `PictureBox`'s `Paint` event with the following code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    // other code but the above line demonstrates the problem
}
```

This for some reason causes the `MenuStrip` to white out--I can't see the text until I hover over it--even though the `PictureBox` does not overlap the `MenuStrip` at all. I can put a `menuStrip1.Update()` at the end of the function above, but that causes other problems.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this in the paint event. I am surprised your application is not crashing, as I would have expected changing the image to cause the Paint event to fire again - and therefore enter an endless loop... I might be wrong though

Comment: I remember having a good reason for using the Paint event, but it is escaping me now. Not using that certainly solves a lot of problems.

Comment: Paint is generally used for custom drawing, but if you want custom drawing then you will be better off using a `Panel` anyway

Comment: I am actually using a PictureBox inside of a Panel as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048715/c-sharp-panel-autoscroll-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly assigning to the `PictureBox` while in the event, use the provided `PaintEventArgs` to do any drawing.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Gray);
    }
```