# how to enable auto scroll down in a panel when some control is added in the bottom in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an application where data is getting generated at the run time inside a panel.I want to auto scroll the scroll bar down such that when new data is generated it is always visible to the user.
I have already set AutoScroll=true;
What to do next ?
Can someone help here ?

Comment: Hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048715/c-sharp-panel-autoscroll-doesnt-work

Comment: What's in the panel?

Comment: You may have to [do it programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752970/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-panel)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after the add logic:

```
ContainerObject.ScrollControlIntoView(newItemInstance);
```